# "Sum of power" for prime numbers

Tags: summation, power-series

I use Euler–Maclaurin formula, Faulhaber's formula and Bernoulli polynomials for "sum of powers" for this type $\sum_{t=1}^nt^k$. but I don't know to find compact form when sum is taken from first prime numbers

Does there exist general formula for this sum?
$$2^n+3^n+5^n+11^n...+p^n$$

Answer (score 8):

Almost certainly not: if there were a "general formula" for $\sum_{i=1}^r p_i^n$
for even a single $n$, you'd also have a "general formula" for the prime numbers by
$$p_r=\sqrt[n]{\left(\text{“general formula” for }\sum_{i=1}^r p_i^n\right) - \left(\text{“general formula” for }\sum_{i=1}^{r-1}p_i^n\right)}$$